# Why an attribute of the class cannot be called?

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova

I am modifying the code of openstack-nova.

After adding a RESTful api, I got this error:

```
eption during message handling: AttributeError: 'SchedulerReportClient' object has no attribute 'obj_to_primitive'
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/server.py", line 163, in _process_incoming
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     res = self.dispatcher.dispatch(message)
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 268, in dispatch
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     return self._do_dispatch(endpoint, method, ctxt, args)
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 195, in _do_dispatch
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     return self.serializer.serialize_entity(ctxt, result)
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/openstack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/rpc.py", line 130, in serialize_entity
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     return self._base.serialize_entity(context, entity)
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/openstack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/objects/base.py", line 237, in serialize_entity
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     entity)
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/openstack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/objects/base.py", line 223, in _process_iterable
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     for k, v in values.items()})
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/openstack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/objects/base.py", line 223, in <dictcomp>
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     for k, v in values.items()})
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/openstack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/objects/base.py", line 245, in serialize_entity
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     entity = entity.obj_to_primitive()
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/openstack/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/scheduler/client/__init__.py", line 37, in __run_method
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     return getattr(self.instance, __name)(*args, **kwargs)
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server AttributeError: 'SchedulerReportClient' object has no attribute 'obj_to_primitive'
2018-08-30 23:08:10.904 1637 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server
```

Associated code is:

```
def serialize_entity(self, context, entity):
    if isinstance(entity, (tuple, list, set, dict)):
        entity = self._process_iterable(context, self.serialize_entity, entity)
    elif (hasattr(entity, 'obj_to_primitive') and callable(entity.obj_to_primitive)):
        entity = entity.obj_to_primitive()
    return entity
```

My question is, `hasattr(entity, 'obj_to_primitive')` is true, so why `entity.obj_to_primitive()` raises exception?

Comment: `obj_to_primitive`  is also callable. Both `hasattr(entity, 'obj_to_primitive')` and `callable(entity.obj_to_primitive)` are true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the last line of the stack trace.  You *are* calling the “method”, but it’s just a wrapper for a corresponding method on `self.instance` and it’s *that* `getattr` that’s failing.  The outer attribute lookup succeeded in creating the wrapper, which made `hasattr` happy, and the wrapper is indeed `callable`.

The `hasattr` test would work if the `getattr(self.instance, __name)` were computed when the wrapper was *created*.  If the wrapper’s only purpose is to be *called* (rather than, say, having methods of its own), it could perform a `callable` check of its own as well.  But Python gives itself to EAFP, so here we are.